# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, kerberos

I want to run https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos on my machine (via Intellij idea). The module I am trying to build and run is `sec-server-spnego-form-auth`, but I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null` as well as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context`, which comes because of the first error, I guess.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Stacktrace:

```
2017-08-22 13:28:44.457 ERROR 15064 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.app.Application.main(Application.java:13)

2017-08-22 13:28:44.457  INFO 15064 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ec4505: startup date [Tue Aug 22 13:28:44 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-22 13:28:44.458  WARN 15064 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ec4505: startup date [Tue Aug 22 13:28:44 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.app.Application.main(Application.java:13)

2017-08-22 13:28:44.459  WARN 15064 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ec4505: startup date [Tue Aug 22 13:28:44 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.app.Application.main(Application.java:13)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.app.Application.main(Application.java:13)
2017-08-22 13:28:44.459  INFO 15064 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@192cfe: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,application,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,mvcConfig,webSecurityConfig]; root of factory hierarchy

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: please post your `pom.xml` or `gradle.build`, beside that code and the stack trace would be useful to trace the issue

Comment: `gradle.build` and `pom.xml` are exactly like in the repository, haven't changed anything.

Comment: are you using Java 1.7 and following [the instruction](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos#prerequisites)?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8. I suppose it shouldn't be a problem as it is a higher version of Java. Or it may be a problem?

I did all the other steps as described, without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it just by taking only the module I need and copying it to a fresh project. Also, I had to use application.properties instead of .yml file, and it worked like a charm.

Not the best solution but it worked.